# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Can someone please provide code to fix this error?

*"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ICollection'*

Essentially, I'm trying to save/bind a value from a collection of objects.

```
@model MVC3.Models.Parent

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bs[0].Val) 

public  class A
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public  class B
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`ICollection`s are not ordered, so that cannot be indexed.

Instead, you should use a separate ViewModel class with `IList<T>` property.

Comment: thx for reply. I'm pretty new to mvc3. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IList`

```
public  class A
{
   public int Name { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```