# EditorForModel not working with ICollection MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

We have the below model:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int SampleId { get; set; }
    public int ToTestId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SampleCondition> Child_SampleConditions { get; set; }
}
```

I am rendering them in my view as below:

```
@model Sample
@{
    string cntlrName = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    List<SampleCondition> sampleConditions  = Model.Child_SampleConditions.ToList();
    if (d2l.NullOrEmpty(sampleConditions))
    {
        Model.Child_SampleConditions .Add(new SampleCondition());
    }
    List<SampleCondition> sampleConditions = Model.Child_SampleConditions as                List<SampleCondition>;
    }
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.d2_HiddenFor(O => O.SampleId)

    <div class="@BOOTSTRAP.ROW">
        @Html.ManyToOneFieldFor(Model, O => O.ToTestId, allowed: CrudFlag.Editable)
        @Html.FieldFor(O => O.Name, allowed: CrudFlag.Editable)
        @Html.FieldFor(O => sampleConditions[0].ConditionValue, allowed:CrudFlag.Editable)
    </div>
```

Please look at the third filed in div, sampleConditions[0].ConditionValue. The html input field for this control is rendering with the name "[0].ConditionValue" instead of "Child_SampleConditions[0].ConditionValue". Thats why when I post this form, the Child_SampleConditions are not automatically binded to the model object into post method.

can somebody advise how to render ICollection input field names correctly so that they can automatically gets model binded.

NOTE: Please exclude the custom model binder options.

EDIT: I am providing some more information here. 
In the ManyToOneFieldFor mehtod, the name retrieved using the below helper:

```
 string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
```

It just returns, [0].ConditionValue but not Child_SampleConditions[0].ConditionValue.

Please advise..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
O => sampleConditions[0].ConditionValue
```

write:

```
O => O.Child_SampleConditions[0].ConditionValue
```

**EDIT:**

Create a ViewModel with `IList` as `ICollection` cannot be indexed:

```
public class SampleVM
{
    public int SampleId { get; set; }
    public int ToTestId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SampleCondition> Child_SampleConditions { get; set; }
}
```

Reference link:[Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870093/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-icollection)

Comment: no that does not work. it gives compile time error: Error 4 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SampleBiz.Models.Objects.SampleCondition>'

Comment: you cannot index ``ICollection`` use ``IList`` by creating a view model

Comment: I dont think I can change the model. They are designed by architect. Are there any consequences of changing ICollection to IList?

Comment: you have to create a view model specific to view not your data model

Comment: and how can I assign my data model to view model 
?

Comment: You need to google only asp.mnet mvc view models you will find alot of information